# Parsing Windows Eventlog Message

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

I need to extract the Message column's "Account For Which Logon Failed:" portion of the below code:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Security"; ID=4625} | Select-Object TimeCreated, Message | Format-Table -wrap
```

No luck so far, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "No luck so far" - what have you tried?  What was the result?  Posting an example of the 'Message' value will make it easier for people to help.

Comment: Just some rudimentary scripting. I'm not a Powershell nor a regex person so it is just some random gibberish. This might be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302023/grab-username-from-get-winevent?rq=2 what I'm looking for but still it gives the complete output not just a single line.

Comment: You can convert an event object to xml and then each event data is in its own property.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154238/powershell-getting-advanced-eventlog-informations-xml